# ¿Cómo importar una tabla desde SQLen donde las columnas sean de la clase character?

Tags: sql, r

para importar tablas desde SQL uso la función `sqlQuery` del paquete `RODBC`.

Un ejemplo de la asignación es la siguiente:

```
df <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "Select * from Results")
```

Pero todas las variables al importarse se convierten en `factores`. Lo he intentado cambiar con la función `as.data.frame` especificando el argumento `stringsAsFactors`, asímismo, he usado al función `apply` de la siguiente manera, pero no logro convertirlo a `character`.

```
df1<-as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, as.character))
```

Lo he hecho con un `for`, pero creo que puede haber otra manera más sencilla.

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un comportamiento que podríamos llamar "clásico" y que es bastante controvertido, es la costumbre de muchas funciones que generan `data.frames` de tratar las cadenas como `factors`, tal es el caso de la simple función de creación `data.frame()` como también en este caso, es el comportamiento de [`sqlQuery()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-16/topics/sqlQuery).

De cualquier forma, este comportamiento puede modificarse, para esto existe el parámetro, `stringsAsFactors`, que obviamente por defecto asume el valor `TRUE`

```
df <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "Select * from Results", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Aunque no es recomendable, esto puede modificarse de forma global `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Verificado contra un **SQL Server**:

```
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from information_schema.tables')
str(res)

'data.frame':   7 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ TABLE_CATALOG: Factor w/ 1 level "master": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ TABLE_SCHEMA : Factor w/ 1 level "dbo": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ TABLE_NAME   : Factor w/ 7 levels "MSreplication_options",..: 3 4 5 7 6 1 2
 $ TABLE_TYPE   : Factor w/ 2 levels "BASE TABLE","VIEW": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

Usando `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from information_schema.tables', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(res)

'data.frame':   7 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ TABLE_CATALOG: chr  "master" "master" "master" "master" ...
 $ TABLE_SCHEMA : chr  "dbo" "dbo" "dbo" "dbo" ...
 $ TABLE_NAME   : chr  "spt_fallback_db" "spt_fallback_dev" "spt_fallback_usg" "spt_values" ...
 $ TABLE_TYPE   : chr  "BASE TABLE" "BASE TABLE" "BASE TABLE" "VIEW" ...
```

Comment: Patricio, usé esa opción. Pero no logré convertirlo a character., creo que ese argumento sólo sirve si se usa con la función `sqlGetResults`

Comment: El parámetro esta documentado en la función, pero ya conozco un caso que la documentación no se condice con la realidad, dejame verificar la función.

Comment: @ARSENALCOYG, ahí lo verifiqué conectándome con un SQL Server, y funciona como se espera (RODBV v‘1.3.16). Saludos

Comment: Reinstale el paquete y ahora si se logra hacer. Muchas gracias Patricio.

Comment: Patricio, una pregunta adicional. 
Por qué me sale el siguiente mensaje? `Warning message:
In names(sys.call()) %in% c("", "exact") : closing unused RODBC handle 3`

Comment: Si no cierras la conexión de forma explicita con `odbcClose()` luego de efectuar la consulta, al dejar de usar la misma, se cierra automáticamente y se emite ese warning.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.